# Could adding engaging business Facebook posts to our Google My Business Listing make it more engaging?

Tags: facebook, google-my-business

We recently got our Google My Business Listing (GMBL) up and running for our yoga training business. For a number of years we've had an active FB page and we post about 2-3 post per week on our FB page.

Our FB posts are nice and get good engagement. So we think putting all our FB posts onto our GMBL would be good. But we want to check with some experts first.

Should we post all our FB posts onto our GMBL? Is that good for making our GMBL more engaging?

Comment: I suggest adding just a few of the better ones.  GMBL is generally a static "flyer" rather than a constantly updated resource.

Comment: Sounds good to me. Thanks! I'm new to SEO/SEM so this is helpful. Cheers,